# Reading logged in user variable in database

Tags: java, android, backendless

Is it possible to read the logged in user name in Backendless user database ,because certain users should get a different first activity when logged in on app ?

```
Backendless.UserService.login( email, password, true );
            boolean isValidLogin = Backendless.UserService.isValidLogin();
            Log.i( "MYAPP", "[SYNC] Is login valid? - " + isValidLogin );
            AsyncCallback<Boolean> isValidLoginCallback = new AsyncCallback<Boolean>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleResponse( Boolean response )
                {
                    //WANT TO TEST THE NAME OF LOGGED IN USER HERE
                    Log.i( "MYAPP", "[ASYNC] Is login valid? - " + response );
                }

                @Override
                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault)
                {
                    Log.i( "MYAPP", "Error - " + fault );
                }

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Backendless.UserService.login( email, password,
                new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser response) {
                           if(response!=null) 
                           //get user logged details
                        BackendlessUser user=Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser();
                        String userId = UserIdStorageFactory.instance().getStorage().get();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "User has been logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), fault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to answer the original question: your example _performs_ a login, while the question is how to retrieve the currently logged in user.

Comment: Seems to be much closer, thanks! It would be good if this answer would suffice, but still I bothered to give a detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some confusion you have, judging from your code. I'll try to explain the concepts separately.

First, you're passing the `stayLoggedIn` argument as `true` while logging in. What this means is that if the user of your app closes the application, and then reopens it after a while, you don't need to perform login again - it will stay persisted since the first time.

Second, there is a small caveat in using `stayLoggedIn = true` parameter. Under the hood it just stores the `user-token` value on your device, effectively making the requests after the app restart authorized even if you don't perform login again. But the caveat is that the login may become invalid due to certain circumstances, like if you configured the login to expire or you expired in manually by switching the multiple login on console. This is when you need the `isValidLogin()` call: it returns `true` is the stored token is still valid, and `false` otherwise.

The confusion I see is that you call `isValidLogin` right after the `login` call, which doesn't make sense - obviously it is valid, because you just did it. The proper flow would be to first call `isValidLogin` and *only if it returns false* perform `login` afterwards. This effectively saves a bit of login-logouts, which may pollute your analytics and will generally be a little slower.

Now, answering your question, usually you need neither `login` nor `isValidLogin` call to retrieve the currently logged in user. Assuming that you've called `login` with `stayLoggedIn = true` some time earlier, you just need to retrieve current user's ID and then use it to retrieve user's object itself. Here's a code that would do that:

```
final String currentUserId = UserIdStorageFactory.instance().getStorage().get();
BackendlessUser currentUser = Backendless.Data.of( BackendlessUser.class ).findById( currentUserId );
```

But note that `currentUserId` may be `null in case you haven't called`login`with`stayLoggedIn = true`, in that case you'll have to do login and get a user in response:

```
BackendlessUser currentUser = Backendless.UserService.login( "email", "password", true );
```

And of course remember that in Android you have to either use analogical async methods (the ones accepting `AsyncCallback`) or use `AsyncTask` or anything to perform the request outside of the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what I was trying to do, got this answer from the Backendless documentation.

```
 BackendlessUser user = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser();
  if( user != null )
  {
    // get user's phone number (i.e. custom property)
    String phoneNumber = (String) user.getProperty( "phoneNumber" );
    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, 
                    String.format( "phone number: %s", phoneNumber ), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
```